Aioimaplib\Python | Как подключить прокси к aioimaplib?
Нужно чтобы запрос входа на почту по imap прошел через прокси socks5 ip:port:login:password, но у меня ничего не получается.
код который заходит на аккаунт без прокси ниже.
import aioimaplib

imap_client = aioimaplib.IMAP4(host='imap-mail.outlook.com')
await imap_client.wait_hello_from_server()
login_result = await imap_client.login('jacquelynneto1994@hotmail.com', 'HuN06geR')

